# Read Numbers in Counter using OCR Currently using PyTesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read numbers in operation counters using a Python Backend. Currently using PyTesseract to read the numbers but it is very inconsistent and not giving the right output.

I have tried the following Preprocessing methods per the documentation below but no good luck.

[Tesseract Documentation](https://github.com/NanoNets/ocr-with-tesseract/blob/master/tesseract-tutorial.ipynb)

Here are a couple of sample images that I'm using for testing purposes

[image: Counter Image1]
[image: Counter Image 2]
[image: Counter Image 3]

The config that I'm using is this

```
'--oem 3 --psm 7 outputbase digits -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
```

Please advise if I'm missing anything or if there are better ways to preprocess these images.

Comment: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html

Comment: What does this have to do with OpenCV exactly?

Comment: @DanMašek OpenCV for the preprocessing stuff that perhaps are needed before processing through pytesseract